# duplicate deletion problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on a database where i have two tables.

### BILL_MASTER (master_table)

Bill_Master_ID
Consumer_No

### BILL_GENERATION (Detail table)

Bill_Master_ID

Somehow user has inserted two identical consumer #'s in bill master but bill_master_id is different..here is the example of bill_master table

```
Bill_Master_ID   Consumer_No
1                1234567890
2                1234567890
```

now user has made one transaction of bill_master_id "1" and record exists in Bill_Generation table.

What i want to do is when i pass consumer # in SQL statement as parameter it check if selected consumer# Bill_master_id exist in bill_generation or not. If yes then count return should be 1 else 0.

Comment: Adding a `Unique Constraint` on `Consumer_No` would do just that and would let the database validate (and reject) the invalid input.

Comment: If BILL_MASTER should only allow a single Consumer_No entry then you should also look at applying a unique constraint on that column to protect the data integrity within the DB - whilst it's good to have the checking in your SQL statements the schema should be set up with appropriate constraints to protect the data if someone bypasses your logic and hits the tables directly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you want.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(consumer_no) FROM bill_master m 
    inner join bill_generation g on m.bill_master_id=g.bill_master_id
    WHERE consumer_no=1234567890
   ) > 1
   SELECT 1
ELSE
   SELECT 0
```

Comment: I guess it won't work using query...grimming thanks for your effort unfortunately didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The title is misleading, this has nothing to do with deletion unless that's additional to the question.

So what you mean is, based on consumer no, you need to find any record in bill_generation for any of the consumer's ids in bill_master?

```
select case when exists (
    select *
    from bill_master m
    inner join bill_generation g on g.bill_master_id = m.bill_master_id
    where m.consumer_no = 1234   -- or some number
    ) then 1 else 0 end
```

To actually delete records from bill_master except the lowest id, you can use this

```
;with tmp as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by consumer_no order by bill_master_id)
    from bill_master)
 delete tmp where rn > 1
```

Comment: well my main concern is BILL_MASTER_ID against the same consumer numbers of two records. Consumer # is same but BILL_MASTER_ID is unique. What i wanted is to check if consumer #s' master ID is present in Bill_Generation table or not. I guess i was unable to explain my question in proper manner so apologize.